# Synergy: ssl certificate doesn't exist?

Tags: ssl, synergy

I have installed Synergy v1.8.8 on my Ubuntu. It works fine as a server until the next reboot. Once I restart the machine, it shows the following errors:

```
[2020-02-14T11:58:08] ERROR: ssl certificate doesn't exist: /.synergy/SSL/Synergy.pem
    /build/synergy-iliE6X/synergy-1.8.8-stable+dfsg.1/src/lib/net/SecureSocket.cpp,617
```

The only workaround I found so far is to reinstall Synergy. Then works fine (until the next reboot).

How can I fix it pernamently?

*Edit #1:* The interesting thing is that `/.synergy/SSL/Synergy.pem` is not present at all, both in situation when Synergy manages to start and in situation when it fails.

*Edit #2:* Here's `synergy.conf` I use:

```
section: screens
    X:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        switchCorners = none 
        switchCornerSize = 0
    Y:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        switchCorners = none 
        switchCornerSize = 0
end

section: aliases
end

section: links
    X:
        right = Y
    Y:
        left = X
end

section: options
    relativeMouseMoves = false
    screenSaverSync = true
    win32KeepForeground = false
    clipboardSharing = true
    switchCorners = none 
    switchCornerSize = 0
end
```

Comment: Does the certificate file actually exist?  Are you tell from your audit logs what is happening to the certificate file?  When Synergy works, does the error still get generated, which of course would be an indication the certificate error is a red hearing.  I have had issues that indicated a database could not be accessed, come to find out, the service never started due to the fact the drive was full of logs preventing the service from successfully starting.  But due to disk usage, the logs, didn't indicate that was the case because they could not be created.

Comment: @Ramhound  `/.synergy/SSL/Synergy.pem` is not present at all, both in situation when Synergy manages to start and in situation when it fails. So the error message is really misleading. Why would it need such a file?

Comment: That’s your certificate file.  There should be a Synergy configuration file.  We need the relevant information from that

Comment: @Ramhound I've included `synergy.conf` file. It contains no relevant information.